# Несколько классов в одном файле

Tags: c++, qt

Является ли дурным тоном описывать и реализовывать несколько классов в одном файле-заголовочнике и одном .срр-файле соответственно?
Например, я имею некий класс окна с несколькими виджетами на нем. Среди них есть `QTreeView` и `QTableView`, базирующиеся на своих моделях, унаследованных от `QAbstractItemModel`.  Можно ли объявить все три класса в одном .h файле и реализовать их в одном .срр файле? Или лучше как в java, один класс - один файл?

Comment: Удобнее по одному, особенно если имя файла совпадает с классом.

Comment: Дело вкуса, скорее. Если классы связаны логически, семантически, так сказать - логичнее их собрать вместе. Если нет - разнести по разным файлам. *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: @Harry В том-то и дело, эти классы связаны по смыслу, реализация GUI.

Comment: Тогда не вижу никакого криминала в том, чтобы разместить их вместе... Разве что они очень большие - но очень большие классы сами по себе не очень хорошо.

Comment: А вы гляньте в исходники того же Qt. Они там таким не брезгуют

Comment: @Artik если унаследованные классы имеют малый функционал (добавочный), например добавление одной переменной, то будьте свободны объявить все в одном файле.

Answer (score 1):

Из моих наблюдений, многие open-source проекты запросто объединяют несколько классов в один файл. Как правило, объединённые классы зачастую являются наследниками одного и того же класса, либо наследниками друг друга. Объединение происходит по принципу функциональности и использовании классов в Вашей программе.

Например, все классы, которые унаследуют от некого `QUndoCommand` можно разместить в один файл "UndoCommands.h". Как правило, унаследованные классы будут достаточно маленькими по содержанию (только 2 пере-определённые функции - `undo()` и `redo()` в каждом). При использовании классов, гораздо проще включить один файл `#include "UndoCommands.h"`, чем перечислять все многочисленные унаследованные классы, если бы каждый из них находился в отдельном файле.

Comment: В моём случае, классы не унаследованы от одного предка, но связаны по назначению. Меня интересовало, можно ли в файлы класса окна (среди виджетов которого есть QTreeView) запихнуть реализацию класса-наследника QAbstractItemModel, на основе которого и строится QTreeView?

Comment: Вообще, нет строгих правил о том, каким образом Вы размещаете Ваши классы. Хотя модель наверно лучше разделять от её вида. С другой стороны, если ваша `QAbstractItemModel` используется **только** в вашем `QTreeView`, в этом случае нет ничего плохого в объединении в один файл.

Comment: В том-то и дело, модель используется только с этой вьюшкой.